# R: Ignorance of logical condition

Tags: r

I am trying to find *k* maximum values from a global data.frame and update a logical variable *outlier* in each iteration. This is the code I am using

```
while(k > 0){
             #find the max value index 
             index = which(data$value==max(data$value[which(data$brand==brand_rm & 
                             data$outlier == FALSE)],na.rm = T))[1]
             #update outlier column 
             data$outlier[index] <<- TRUE
                        k = k - 1
                      }
```

However it will only work in the first iteration and will ignore the *data$outlier == FALSE* condtion in the next iterations. Can you please explain why this happens and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the better approach to do this which is:

```
while(k > 0){
          #find the outlier index 
          row_to_remove = which(data[,value]==max(data[data$outlier ==FALSE & 
          data$brand==brand_rm ,value]))
           ata$outlier[row_to_remove] <<- TRUE 
                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question right, you don't even need a loop for that. See my reproducible example below.

```
data <- data.frame(value=11:20, outlier=FALSE)
k <- 2
kth_value = sort(data$value, decreasing = TRUE)[k] #Get the Kth highest value

data$outlier <- ifelse( data$value>=kth_value,  TRUE, FALSE) #Compare to the kth
```